# Issue getting ZipArchive::close() to function and a zip folder to be created php

Tags: php, file, file-upload, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm attempting to create a zip attachment from files that were just uploaded. To confirm, the files I am attempting to upload are uploading. The issue is isolated to the zip part and the code below.

This is the error I am receiving:

> **Warning**:  ZipArchive::close(): Can't remove file: No such file
>   or directory in

For this line of code:

```
$f->close();
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the full code:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$fu = new fileUpload();
$filename = $fu->upload();
$uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();
$extensions = ['pdf','jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];

$differentExtensions = array_diff($uploadedFileTypes, $extensions);
if (count($differentExtensions) > 0) { 
    $f = new ZipArchive();
    $zip = $f->open('uploads/' . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][0] . ".zip", ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
    if ($zip) {
        for ($index = 0; $index < count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']); $index++) {
            $f->addFile($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$index], $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$index]);
        }
        $f->close();

        $message["attachment[0]"] = curl_file_create("uploads/{$file['uploadedFile']['name'][0]}.zip",
            pathinfo("uploads/{$file['uploadedFile']['name'][0]}.zip", PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
            $file['uploadedFile']['name'][0] . ".zip");
    }
```

Fileupload Class:

```
class fileUpload
{

public function __construct()
{}

public $imageFileTypes = [];

public function getImageFileTypes()
{
     return $this->imageFileTypes;
}

public function upload() {

    if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])) {

        $file_count = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
        $results = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
//          echo $file['uploadedFile']['name'][$index] . "\n";

            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            //$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
             // here's the important bit
            $this->imageFileTypes[] = $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                return 0;
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
                    $results[] = basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return $results;
```

Full code for the file the zip attempt is on:

```
$files = null;
// print_r($_FILES);
if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])) {

    if ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] == 1) {
        $error = "The file {$_POST['first_name']} attempted to upload is too large. Contact them for an alternate way to send this file.";
        $template = str_replace("{filename}", "$error", $template);
    }

    $date = new DateTime();
    $fu = new fileUpload();
    $filename = $fu->upload();
    $uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();
    //$fileTypeString = implode( ", ", $uploadedFileTypes);
    $extensions = ['pdf','jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];
    //file_put_contents('file_type_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r($uploadedFileTypes, true), FILE_APPEND);

    $differentExtensions = array_diff($uploadedFileTypes, $extensions);
    if (count($differentExtensions) > 0) {
        file_put_contents('file_norm_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r('There were other types of files uploaded', true), FILE_APPEND);  
        $f = new ZipArchive();
        $zip = $f->open('uploads/' . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][0] . ".zip", ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
        //var_dump($f);
        //var_dump($zip);
        if ($zip) {
            for ($index = 0; $index < count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']); $index++) {
//                        echo $file['uploadedFile']['name'][$index] . "\n";
                $f->addFile($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$index], $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$index]);
            }
            $check = $f->addFile($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$index], $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$index]);
            var_dump($check);
            $f->close();

            $message["attachment[0]"] = curl_file_create("uploads/{$file['uploadedFile']['name'][0]}.zip",
                pathinfo("uploads/{$file['uploadedFile']['name'][0]}.zip", PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
                $file['uploadedFile']['name'][0] . ".zip");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Could not zip the files.");
        }
    } else {
        $out = (count($filename) > 1 ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) > 1 ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
        foreach ($filename as $indFile) {
            //print_r($template);
            $out .= "<li><a href='/php/uploads/{$indFile}'>{$indFile}</a></li>";
        }
        $out .= '</ul>';
        $template = str_replace("{filename}", $out, $template);
    }

    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        foreach($file['name'] as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                //echo "name is empty!";
                $template = str_replace("{filename}", '', $template);
            }   
            if ($file['error'][$key] != 4) {
                //echo "error code is 4";
            }
        }
    }
    clearstatcache();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$zip` or `$f`? Please share.

Comment: @zbee `var_dump($zip);` outputs `bool(true)`

Comment: `var_dump($f)` : `object(ZipArchive)#5 (5) {
  ["status"]=>
  int(0)
  ["statusSys"]=>
  int(0)
  ["numFiles"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filename"]=>
  string(53) "/php/uploads/analytics.PNG.zip"
  ["comment"]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Comment: It sounds like it's not adding the files. Is `$f->addFile()` returning `false`? Do the files exist and are readable, are there restrictions from `open_basedir`, etc?

Comment: I don't think you have to actually copy the files to a permanent location before trying to zip them; but have you tried to do that? The uploaded files in PHP are odd little ghosts that can be difficult to work with in some contexts.

Comment: `$check = $f->addFile(.....); var_dump($check);` would be one way. Reason I mentioned it might not be adding the files is [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php#118392) on the manual pge.

Comment: @cOle2 I got the following: `<b>Notice</b>:  ZipArchive::addFile(): Empty string as filename in` and then `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 2 in`......Could this be the issue? `$_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']`. I use `$filename` elsewhere.

Comment: That def sounds like the issue. No filename means no file added which results in your `Can't remove file` error message.

Comment: @cOle2 I just added my fileupload class to my question. I'm not sure if this will help. The files are definitely being uploaded though. I check every time I try and they are in the uploads folder.

Comment: @c I also added the full code for the file this zip is on. The name is recognized as not being empty here. That is how we even get to the zip code. `if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]))`

Comment: When var_dumping the `$_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]`, the files output the data. So I don't get it :`array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "airport.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(21) "fath_09304701_6_0.par"
}`

Comment: I just looked at the `var_dump($f)` again. Could the issue be that my original extension is still included? `["filename"]=>
  string(53) "/public_html/php/uploads/afterglow.png.zip"`

Comment: First thing that stands out to me is you're moving the uploaded files in the `$fu->upload()` call but then trying to add them to the zip from the `$_FILES` array which would be not point to where they're moved to. Maybe make the `$results` array with `$target_file` instead of `basename($_FILES....)` and in your script loop through `$filename` instead of the `$_FILES` array which should be the correct location.

Comment: @cOle2 Well `$filename` is `$filename = $fu->upload();`, which is the return for the results array. So wouldn't this be the same thing? `$zip = $f->open($target_dir . $filename[0] . ".zip", ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);` .... `$target_dir = "uploads/";`

Comment: Yes its fine for the `$f->open()` call because its just the name you are using there but in `$f->addFile()` you are using the `$_FILES` array to add the file but you moved them in the `$fu->upload()` call.

Comment: @cOle2 Then what would you recommend doing then? If I added it, how can I make it the zip then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments it looks like you are moving the uploaded file to the `uploads/` dir in your `$fu->upload()` call however when you are zipping them you are referencing the 'old' location of the files by using the `$_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']` array for its location.

In your script change:

```
    $f->addFile($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$index], $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$index]);
```

to

```
    $f->addFile('uploads/'.basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$index], basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$index]);
```

Comment: Thanks! This created the zip, but the zip isn't being retrieved. Do I have to modify this part then? `$message["attachment[0]"] = curl_file_create("uploads/{$filename[0]}.zip",
     pathinfo("uploads/{$filename[0]}.zip", PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
     $filename[0] . ".zip");`

Comment: I'd reference the zip path/filename in the same way you do in the `$f->open()` call: `'uploads/' . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][0] . ".zip"` but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help!